# alternative definition of Affine map

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

> Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function on real vector spaces (note that $X,Y$ have arbitrary dimensions). If $T(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ is linear, $f$ is called an affine map.

Prove that $f$ is affine if and only if $f\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^na_kx_k\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n a_k f(x_k),\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,\ \forall x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in X,\ \forall a_k\in\mathbb R\text{ such that }\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^na_k=1 \ .$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $f$ is affine. Then the $T$ above is linear. Then $f(x) = Tx + f(0)$.

Now suppose $\sum_k a_k =1$. Then $f(\sum_k a_k x_k ) = \sum_k a_k T x_k + f(0)$, by linearity, and since $\sum_k a_k =1$, we have 
$\sum_k a_k T x_k + f(0) = \sum_k a_k (T x_k + f(0)) = \sum_k a_k f(x_k)$, as required.

For the other direction, suppose $f(\sum_k a_k x_k ) = \sum_k a_k f(x_k)$ whenever $\sum_k a_k =1$. Define $T(x) = f(x)-f(0)$. We want to show that $T$ is linear. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
T(\lambda x) &=& f(\lambda x)-f(0) \\
&=&  f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)0) + f(0) \\
&=&  \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(0)-f(0) \\
&=&  \lambda(f(x)-f(0)) \\
&=&  \lambda T(x)
\end{eqnarray}

Now consider
\begin{eqnarray}
T\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) &=& f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) -f(0) \\
&=&  \frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(y)) -f(0) \\
&=&  \frac{1}{2}(f(x)-f(0)+f(y) -f(0) ) \\
&=&  \frac{1}{2}(T(x) + T(y))
\end{eqnarray}

Combining this with the previous result, we have $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$, hence $T$ is linear.

Comment: @OliverG: I'm not sure what you are asking, the answer above is solely to show that $f$ being affine implies $T$ is linear?

Comment: I misstyped earlier, I'll clarify now.  Why is it that if $f$ is affine then $f(\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)0) = \lambda(x) + (1-\lambda)f(0)$?

Comment: @OliverG: The definition of affine is that for any $t$ we have $f(t x +(1-t)y) = t f(x) + (1-t) f(y)$.

Comment: I think I'm starting with a different definition of an affine map  [i.e. a map $f$ from an affine span of an affine independent set of points to $R^k$ such that $f(\sum t_i x_i)=\sum t_i f(x_i)]$ and don't understand how to derive your definition.  I think I don't understand how, since any point in the affine span is an affine sum of the points, $f(t \sum j_i x_i + (1-t) \sum h_i x_i) = t f(\sum j_i x_i) + (1-t) f(\sum h_i x_i)$.

Comment: @OliverG: Your definition needs the constraint $\sum_i t_i = 1$ in which case the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: My apologies, I was assuming that was taken as known from the phrase affine span.  I'm having trouble understanding why they're equivalent.  By re-writing $f(t \sum j_i x_i + (1-t) \sum h_i x_i) = t f( \sum j_i x_i) + (1-t) f(\sum h_ix_i)$ as much as I can into: $f(t(\sum x_i(j_i-h_i)) + \sum h_ix_i)=t[f(\sum x_i(j_i-h_i)] + f(\sum h_i x_i)$, I can't seem to find a way to show their equality.

Comment: @OliverG: I'm still not sure what you are asking. The question asks to show that the two definitions in the question are equivalent. That is, one definition says that $f$ is affine if it can be expressed as a linear map plus a constant. The other is the more classical definition $f(tx+(1-t)y) = t(f) + (1-t) f(y)$ for all $t$. The latter is equivalent to $f(\sum_k t_k x_k) = \sum_k t_k f(x_k)$ with $\sum_k t_k = 1$.

Comment: Very nice! and +1