# Representation of Affine Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I'm just looking for a reference or the proof that every affine map $f:V\rightarrow W$ between two possible different linear spaces $V$ and $W$:

$$
f[\lambda x+ (1-\lambda) y]=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y), \text{  for all  }  \lambda\in\mathbb{R},
$$

admit always a representation as $f(x)=g(x)+c$ where $g:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map and $c\in W$.

Comment: Update: this question has been already answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566448/alternative-definition-of-affine-map?rq=1